# Get a list of drive letters and types from the registry

Tags: windows

I have several local drives such as C:, D:, F: and so on. Also several CDROM drives.

I want to know where windows store these data (drive letters and drive types).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drive letters can be found here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices
```

Comment: Thanks, But What about Drive Types?

Comment: Thats in the Data column of the keys.

Comment: But it is in Binary, how to translate them? which means local hard drive? Which means CD-Rom?

Comment: They are in Hex IIRC

Comment: Only hard-drives are in hex, other types have long, variable-length Unicode strings. If you open one in the *Edit Binary Value* dialog, you’ll see them. A CD/DVD will be something like `\??\IDE#CdRomSony…`, a flash-drive/memory-card might say `_??_USBSTOR#Disk&Ven_SanDisk&Prod…`, and a hard-drive will have a much shorter string (~12 bytes) of binary data that is not human-readable. You can also use [`DevCon`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272) and [DevManView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/device_manager_view.html) to get a list of hardware that is or has been attached to the system.